# Get the first and last names of all employees who entered the project at the same time as at least one other employee

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

[image]

**Question:
Get the first and last names of all employees who entered the project at the same time as at least one other employee.**

I have four tables Employee, Department, Project, Works_on as shown in below. 
I tried the query:

```
SELECT
emp_fname,
emp_lname 
FROM employee a, 
works_on b 
WHERE a.empno=b.empno;
```

Please let me know what is wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: 1.Don't use comma join syntax. Ever.

Answer (score 1):

for this you need to use both Employee (emp_no,emp_fname,emp_lname) and Works_on (emp_no, Enter_date) relationship linked through emp_no on both tables.

in your query you just used Employee table which does not have connection with checking project submitted times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the below query to get the desired results. I have used partition by clause to group related data.

```
WITH QUERY1 AS (
SELECT EMP_NO,ENTER_DATE, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ENTER_DATE ORDER BY EMP_NO ) "t" FROM works_on)
select t2.emp_fname, t2.emp_lname from query1 t1 inner join employee t2 on t1.emp_no=t2.emp_no where "t">1;

select emp_fname, emp_lname from employee where emp_no in (
SELECT EMP_NO FROM (
SELECT EMP_NO,ENTER_DATE, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ENTER_DATE ORDER BY EMP_NO ) "t" FROM works_on
) query1 where query1."t">1);
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all your query will return employee names who ever worked on any project, and better you would use `INNER JOIN`.
If I understand right; you want employee who work on the same project (let's say ProjectX) and again the employee who entered ProjectX on same time and also there must be at least 2 employee having the same time on ProjectX.

If I am correct with the above:
You need to group your data. For instance first group projects that have at least 2 same enter_date like

```
SELECT Project_no, Enter_date FROM Works_on having Count(emp_no)>=2
```

This will give you all projects and dates that have employee more or equal than 2. Now we can find employee that worked on these projects at these dates.

```
SELECT emp_fname, emp_lname FROM Employee INNER JOIN Works_on AS WO ON WO.emp_no=Employee.emp_no 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Project_no, Enter_date FROM Works_on having Count(emp_no)>=2
) AS PWith2MoreEmployee 
ON PWith2MoreEmployee.Project_no=WO.Project_no 
AND 
PWith2MoreEmployee.Enter_date=WO.Enter_date
```

I hope this will give you what you are looking for.